# Can't add standard toolbox items to Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net

Sorry if my question is asked wrong, I am just starting to learn ASP.NET in VS2008.

I try to follow several tutorials on the web (for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx#wapp_topic5) to create a web page:

- Create new Web Application
- Switch to Default.aspx, Design mode
- Drop a Label from the Standard Toolbox on the page

If I pick the Label from the Standard toolbox category, I can't drop it on the page. I don't know what to do now, since I do exactly what is written in all tutorials. Am I missing something?

I can place only items picked from the HTML category in the Toolbox.

Thanks,
Petr

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, so I will answer myself:

The problem was that one of my directories was named "C#" and the '#' character makes all the problems. I was not able to add controls and I couldn't see manually added controls in the Design mode as ScarletGarden sugests. In other words, '#' must not be in the soluton path.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes design mode messes up. I usually use source mode.

At the same time this might be a VS.NET 2008 deployment issue, too.

Open your default.aspx page in source mode, and paste the code blow into your form element.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

then try to switch design mode can you see the label ?

can you change it's properties ?

and what do you see when you run it ?

And In Visual Studio.NET go to "**Help / About Microsoft Visual Studio**", can you see **Microsoft Visual Web Developer**

If all these questions has negative answers, I think you should deploy Visual Studio's Microsoft Visual Web Developer feature again.

hope this helps.