# Web Form doesn't allow me to add standard toolbox elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, toolbox

I have a .Net Framework 4 Web Project which works properly before I add a *webservice* into it. Then I created a *Web Form with Master Page* but I can't see the asp:Content section in the *Design Mode*. There was no available Standard toolbox items in the toolbox as you can see in the picture: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UzFA.png) (Can't add images because of lack of reputation)

Then I tried a create a fresh new Web Form for getting rid of and master page related errors but Standard toolbox items were not visible again.

Things I've tried so far:

- Removed the web service
- Undo pending changes
- Created a new web form which don't use a master page
- Created a fresh web project
- Resetted settings via **Tools** > **Import and Export Settings**
- Resetted via command line **devenv /ResetSettings**, **devenv /ResetSkipPkgs**
- Repaired Visual Studio via installation .iso
- **UPDATE 1** I've also tried to add a label from source view as mentioned in this 
  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597817/cant-add-standard-toolbox-items-to-default-aspx). When I switched to design mode it throwed an error: "*Error creating control*" [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N24q5.png)

I think this is a project related problem but I'm not sure. The weird thing is some of the old items like an ascx control allow me to add Standard toolbox items but nothing newly created items are allowed me to do this. How can i resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you try to run the TestGov.aspx page? it looks like you can add a label (any control?) in source but there's a problem only with design view?

Comment: maybe the 2nd response here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753589/visual-studio-2010-toolbox-standard-controls-missing

Comment: @wazz TestGov is working. Label and button(added lately) on the page are working. But can't use or edit in the UI / Design Mode. The second response in the given link is misunderstood i think. These are the standard toolBOX items while in the response mentioning the enabling toolBAR items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time googling , and mostly all answers - revolving around

Reset Toolbar
Delete .tbd files from C:\Users(your user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
Using devenv.exe /SafeMode & devenv.exe /ResetSettings.
None of them working out for me, making me more sick.

There is something I did which worked and thought it's worth sharing if it helps someone.

I followed all of the above steps, failing . I did Step 1 & 2 with my project (in VS 2012) open and

Right Click on Toolbox > Choose Items > Pressed Reset > ok.
Then again, Right Click on Toolbox > Add Tab > 'gave it some name' > then again
Reset Toolbox
There was some screen flash/flickering - some loading .

And to my surprise the Grey life ( grey controls ) were now available .

Hope this helps someone like me! :)

Answer (score -1):

in the image, the General tab is open, not the HTML tab. try clicking the HTML tab.

Comment: I have no problem with the HTML items. I can't see standard toolbox items like button, label and the other asp items. The problem is aspx page is acting like an HTML page.

Comment: sorry, mixed up HTML items with Standard.

Answer (score -1):

1 - Right click – your web application project and select Properties -> Web

2- in the server section choose Use IIS Web Server -> then click Create Virtual.

3- Clean your project from any DDLs that was previously complied and compile your project again.

ALSO

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779/en

Comment: Don't answer the same question twice, just add this to your other answer.